# Changing background-position of image having shadow in it with easing effect as if some body has touched it

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have Got the following scenario there is piece of paper as the background having shadow in it. On hover I am changing the background image with no shadow in it. but not really getting that effect

The image is
[image]

My jquery code is

```
$('.noticeBoard').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css({'background-position':'0 -590px'});
            }).mouseout(function() {

                $(this).css({'background-position':'0 0'});
            });
```

any help will be very much appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery CODE should be :

```
$('.noticeBoard').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0 -590px'});
        }).mouseout(function() {

            $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0 0'});
        });
```

You should write it as '**backgroundPosition**' and not '**background-position**'.

Comment: I am not using animate method in css we  can definetly use 'background-position' and if you could answer me the solution it will be better